# Connect to internet to continue

Tags: inno-setup

I there any way to force user to connect to internet , during installation ?

Answer (score 2):

You can check to ensure the user is connected before proceeding.  That would be the best, most non-intrusive way of "forcing" them.

Not knowing what language/technologies you are using, it's hard to answer the question, but simply check for a connection, and until one is found display a "please connect to the internet" message with an "ok" "cancel" option.  Your user will typically like this much more than just automatically connecting.  It's unlikely, however possible, that the user uses dial up or some other pay-per-bit service in which it would be polite to **let the user make the decision to connect or not.**

Comment: This is *what* to do, and *why*.

Comment: "Not knowing what language/technologies you are using"--the question is tagged `inno-setup`. [Inno Setup is an installer builder](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php).

Answer (score 1):

You will need to write some Pascal scripting code in a [[Code]](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_scriptintro.htm) section to check for an Internet connection.